# Pl/SQL package including yearly salary calculation function

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I need a help in creating a package in PL/SQL as following:
A package containing one function and one procedure. Function calculates the yearly salary of particular employee and yearly salary is inserted into the another table with employee id using procedure.
here is  I tried but I don't know how to add a procedure which insert my values
into "particular_emp" table

```
CREATE TABLE particular_emp (
  salary string NOT NULL,
  emp_id NUMBER NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE salary IS
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_yearly_salary(p_sal  IN employees.salary%TYPE,
                                             p_comm IN employees.commission_pct%TYPE)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN (NVL(p_sal, 0) * 12 + (NVL(p_comm, 0) * nvl(p_sal, 0) * 12));
  END get_yearly_salary;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you've written some code but it didn't work, please edit your question to include that code, what you want it to do and what it actually does, including any error messages.  Right now your question gives us no indication that you've made any effort whatsoever to write the code yourself and suggests to us that you want somebody else to write your code for you, for free.

Comment: Sounds a great deal like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did and its working!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE empinfo
IS
FUNCTION YSALARY(p_empno IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
PROCEDURE INSERTSAL (p_empno IN NUMBER);
END empinfo;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY empinfo is
FUNCTION YSALARY(p_empno IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
vsal INTEGER;
BEGIN
vsal :=200;
vsal :=200*12;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA is available');
END;
PROCEDURE INSERTSAL(p_empno IN NUMBER) is
BEGIN
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEESALARY
VALUES(200,YSALARY(1));
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA');
END;
END empinfo;
/
```